# For UITableViewCell (on iPhone) I need to figure out how to get it's current position?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

So, idea is the following. I have UITableViewCell, and when I click on it, I want to show UIActivityIndicatorView right in this cell. I cannot figure out how do I find the X/Y or any position (I can find the frame size of UITableViewCell though but it does not help much :-) for the given cell. 
Any tips? Help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the cell, just add the activity indicator to the cell's contentView as a subview. There's no need to know the cell's position in terms of the table view's coordinate system to position the activity indicator within the cell. If you don't have a reference to the cell, call your table view's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work actually.

This is what I am trying to do:

UITableViewCell *cellView = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cellView.contentView addSubview:cCellWaitView];

// and cCellWaitView is defined in .h, initialized in viewDidLoad

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(spinBegin) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

// where spinBegin is bacially [cCellWaitView startAnimating];

that's it -- and the problem is that nothing changes...

Comment: `[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` (the datasource method) is not the same as `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` (the method of UITableView).